# jib-maven-plugin: How to solve running extension error

Tags: pom.xml, jib, maven-jib

I had an error about `jib-maven-plugin` when mvn verify is run on gitlab, it throws an error saying;

`error running extension 'com.google.cloud.tools.jib.plugins.extension.NullExtension': extension configured but not discovered on Jib runtime classpath: com.bol.axle.jib.maven.extension.scuttle.ScuttleJibMavenPluginExtension`

Any idea how to solve it?

Here's my pom.xml that I tried to solve it;

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
    <artifactId>jib-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>3.3.1</version>

    <!-- 1. have extension classes available on Jib's runtime classpath -->
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.cloud.tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>jib-spring-boot-extension-maven</artifactId>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <configuration>
        <to>
            <image>gcr.io/bolcom-stg-pricestars-795/price-stars:latest</image>
        </to>
        <pluginExtensions>
            <!-- 2. specify extension implementation classes to load -->
            <pluginExtension>
                <implementation>com.google.cloud.tools.jib.maven.extension.springboot.JibSpringBootExtension</implementation>
            </pluginExtension>
        </pluginExtensions>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

Upgrading maven wrapper to 3.8.x fixed the issue!